react-select-async-paginate: (0 , import_use_lazy_ref.useLazyRef) is not a function
I have a custom react component build on storybook. I am using import Select, { components } from 'react-select'; and import { AsyncPaginate, withAsyncPaginate } from 'react-select-async-paginate';
 
My goal is to create a component the works with defaultValues or with async pagination (loadOptions) depending on the props that are passed to the component. The component works fine on storybook and in the stories.
However, the component crashes when I import it to my react app. I have the same versions in both my react-app and my storybook component.
I get this error when importing the component and trying to pass the loadOptions props:
"(0 , import_use_lazy_ref.useLazyRef) is not a function" useAsyncPaginateBase.ts:51 function: useAsyncPaginateBase const optionsCacheRef = useLazyRef(() => getInitialOptionsCache(params));
It only crashed when I pass the loadOptions props.
I tried installing all the same versions both on storybook and my react-app. I tried to create a component just with import { AsyncPaginate } from 'react-select-async-paginate'; 
Again, it works fine on storybook, but it crashed on my react-app and I get the "(0 , import_use_lazy_ref.useLazyRef) is not a function" error.
